# JQuery UI contextMenu AJAX load

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, contextmenu

I got a contextMenu action defined like this :

```
$("#conteneurMenuNotifications").contextmenu({
    delegate: ".hasMenuNotifications",
    autoFocus: true,
    preventContextMenuForPopup: false,
    preventSelect: true,
    taphold: true,
    autoTrigger: false,

    beforeOpen: function(event, ui){

        var request =   $.ajax({type: "GET",
            url: "/getData/var1/var2",
            cache: false
        });

        request.done(function(msg){
            $("#conteneurMenuNotifications").contextmenu("replaceMenu",
                    [{title: "---"},
                     {title: "<b>Notifications</b>", disabled: true}]);

            for(var i = 0; i < msg.length; i ++){
                var notif = msg[i];

                $("#conteneurMenuNotifications").contextmenu("setEntry",
                        [{title: notif.label + "-" + notif.title}]);
            }
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             if (jqXHR.status == "500") {
                 window.location.href = "/foagan/resources/html/indispo.html";
             } else {
                 $("#dialogueTache").html(jqXHR.status + " - " + jqXHR.responseText);
                 $("#dialogueTache").dialog("option", "title", "Erreur");
                 $("#dialogueTache").dialog("open");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The `beforeOpen` can be used for asynchronous request, as explained here https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu/blob/master/README.md

But I got this error on the first call of `.contextmenu` in `request.done` :

```
'this.$menu' a la valeur Null ou n'est pas un objet.
```

It's in french... in english it should be :

```
'this.$menu' as Null value or is not an object.
```

Any idees ?

**EDIT**

I've changed the code like this to use replaceMenu :

```
request.done(function(msg){
            var tab = [];
            tab.push({title: "<b>Notifications</b>", disabled: true}, "---");

            for(var i = 0; i < msg.length; i ++){
                var notif = msg[i];
                tab.push({title: label + '-' + title});
            }
            tab.push({title: "---");
            tab.push({title: "Afficher tout", action: function(event, ui) { debrancherVersAfficherTousEvenements(); });

            $("#conteneurMenuNotifications").contextmenu("replaceMenu", tab);
            //dfd.resolve();
            $("#conteneurMenuNotifications").contextmenu("open", $(".hasMenuNotifications:first"));
        });
```

But now I have an infinite loop on this beforeOpen function !

Comment: Could you create a fiddle/MCVE? The only error i can see in the code above is (according to the readme) you're using `setEntry` wrong: it expects two parameters, but gets just one

Comment: Yes it's a first mistake thanks ! I've changed the code to use replaceMenu because I've got others issues. Question edited !

Comment: It seems that the `contextMenu("open"..)` in the ajax call generate this infinite loop.